# XAML Can't find namespace. sometimes

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, namespaces

Might be a Visual Studio error but it its absolutely infuriating and I can't find the solution or even why its happening.

In my application I have a list of XAML files in the namespace Static Content for dockable panels.

The program runs fine there are no errors anywhere in the program other than a few arbitrary warnings.

some XAML

```
<Window x:Class="Shell" 
    xmlns:ad="clr-namespace:AvalonDock;assembly=AvalonDock"  
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:sc="clr-namespace:StaticContent"
    xmlns:ve="clr-namespace:View_Edit"
    Title="View" Width="1024" Height="800" Icon="/component/Images/View.png" 
    Loaded="OnLoaded" IsVisibleChanged="isVisibleChanged" Closing="OnClosing" Background="#E9ECFB"
    WindowStyle="None">

<Grid x:Name="DockingRegion" Margin="0,50,0,0">
        <ad:DockingManager x:Name="DockManager">
            <ad:ResizingPanel>
                <ad:DocumentPane Margin="0,0,10,0">
                    <sc:StartPage Title="Home Page" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
                        onProjectOpenFail="StartPage_onProjectOpenFail" 
                        onProjectOpenSuccess="StartPage_onProjectOpenSuccess"
                        onProjectCreateSuccess="StartPage_onProjectCreateSuccess"
                        onProjectCreateFail="StartPage_onProjectCreateFail"/>
                </ad:DocumentPane>
                <ad:DockablePane ad:ResizingPanel.ResizeWidth="300" x:Name="ExplorerPane" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold">
                    <sc:AboutTab x:Name="about" Title="About" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                    <sc:ProcessExplorer x:Name="pxProcessExplorer" Title="Process Explorer" FontSize="14"/>
                    <sc:DataExplorer x:Name="adDataExplorer" Title="Data Explorer" FontSize="14"/>
                    <!--<sc:UREPExplorer x:Name="adUREPExplorer" Title="UREP Custom Navigation" FontSize="14" Visibility="Hidden"/>-->
                </ad:DockablePane>
            </ad:ResizingPanel>
        </ad:DockingManager>
    </Grid>
```

The tag sc: is the namespace StaticContent. The namespace includes these files. When opening the project this morning it couldn't find the namespace to reference the XAML pages. After pressing re-build all a number of times and receiving a few "rebuild failed", it just decided to work?

Any Ideas?

Comment: Also opening and closing the project between build attempts. I changed nothing else.

Comment: The designer uses the code you have compiled to check namespaces, this means that if your code wont compile  the designer can't find it, some common tricks to get round this is to close all designer windows before compiling, this removes intelli-sense errors that stop studio even trying to compile the code, second if your code errors when running it can crash the designer which causes all sorts of odd behaviour so try to avoid initialising objects in constructors where possible, closing the project also forces a refresh which corrects out of date references that can likewise cause issues

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem.  I have got all of the latest code from TFS on two machines.  On one, it builds perfectly, on a second, it can't find my Window-inherited class, which my dialogs are all based on, they all report an error.  It's bizarre.

Comment: @JackMiller were you able to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Is 'StaticContent' defined under another assembly?

If so look in the project's Properties and check under 'Default Namepace'
if its what you expected it to be.

Comment: No its in the same project and I have referenced the namespace correctly.